# How to configure lua after Wireshark was installed (Linux)

Tags: linux, lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I had Wireshark-1.10.14 on my Linux machine.
I installed Wireshark-2.6.12 (from source). Now when opening Wireshark,
I see that the Wireshark-2.6.12 is without Lua support (from the Wireshark > help about).

1. What do I need to do in order for the Wireshark to open with Lua?

Comment: Recompile with Lua support?  Also, what version of Lua is installed?  Maybe it needs to be updated too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the lua `5.1` or `5.2` development packages. Note that `wireshark` still does not support `lua 5.3`

On Debian/Ubuntu run

```
sudo apt-get install liblua5.2-dev
```

On Fedora run

```
sudo dnf install compat-lua-devel
```

Also you could find some helper scripts in the `tools` sub-directory that should install all of the development dependencies.

1. [debian-setup](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/wireshark-2.6.12/tools/debian-setup.sh)
2. [rpm-setup.sh](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/wireshark-2.6.12/tools/rpm-setup.sh)

then in the wireshark's build directory execute

```
rm CMakeCache.txt
cmake ..
```